# jQuery keydown function not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need some help with making the following code work properly:

```
$('#entry').keydown(function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

With this textarea field:

```
<textarea id="entry" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
```

I have checked with adding alerts outside of the brackets, and the document is loaded and works fine. I even extract a series of entries from a database right after this, with no errors.

What I'm looking to cook here is a textfield that when pressing Enter simply sends the `.val()` of the field to another function responsible for the AJAX request. But obviously I can't get there when I cannot enter the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#entry').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) someotherFunction(this.value);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krWLA/1/)

Comment: Aha, it simply has to be wrapped in another function. Thank you! I chose to use 'keydown' instead though.

Comment: @MikkelWinther - Yes, that would be the document.ready function (shortcut above), and you usually will want to include that around all your jQuery code. Also, `e.which` is normalized by jQuery, so you should use that for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#entry').live('keydown',function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: Can people **please** stop upvoting answers that use **depreciated methods**. Thank you.