# How to make jQuery Triggers "Press Enter"

Tags: jquery

This code, [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746409/jquery-simulate-to-press-enter), does not work :

```
var e = jQuery.Event( 'keydown', { which: 13 } ); 
jQuery('input').trigger(e);
```

How make that work ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve? My guess is to submit the form, if so, use `$('form').submit()`

Comment: Try to also set the `keyCode` attribute to `13`: $.Event('keydown', { which: 13, keyCode: 13 });

Comment: @BhojendraNepal https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nice guess ^^. Thx for this simple solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery keydown function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787493/jquery-keydown-function-not-working)

Comment: search for jquery event keydown. This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @AdrienLafond No problem. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're just trying to submit the form, a better solution would be to use `submit()` instead of creating a dummy event. Try this:

```
$('form').submit();
```